# Reuse production code in tests : good or bad idea? (Or can I use the same code in test and production)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

We have a piece of production code in our application that reads raw DB rows something like that:

```
 List<Map<String, Object>> results =
        txnNamedJdbcTemplate.queryForList(
            transactionDbQueries.getProperty(QUERY_FETCH_REPORT_DETAILS).trim(), paramMap);
```

, then it does a whole load of field transformations to produce an object of desired structure:

```
private Report extractReportData(long reportId, List<Map<String, Object>> results) {
    Map<String, Object> reportRow = results.get(0);
    Timestamp completeTs = (Timestamp) reportRow.getOrDefault(RS_PARAM_END_DATETIME, null);
    Timestamp lastOpenedTs =
        (Timestamp) reportRow.getOrDefault(RS_PARAM_LAST_OPENED_DATETIME, null);
    String reportData =
        reportRow.get(RS_PARAM_REPORT_DATA) == null
            ? StringUtils.EMPTY
            : ((PGobject) reportRow.get(RS_PARAM_REPORT_DATA)).getValue();
    Duration executionTime =
        reportRow.containsKey(RS_PARAM_DURATION)
            ? Duration.ofSeconds(Long.parseLong(reportRow.get(RS_PARAM_DURATION).toString()))
            : null;
    String reportRunLevel = (String) reportRow.getOrDefault(RS_PARAM_ACCESS_LEVEL, null);
    boolean reportOpened = (Boolean) reportRow.getOrDefault(RS_PARAM_OPENED_STATUS, Boolean.FALSE);
    String reportCategory = (String) reportRow.getOrDefault(RS_PARAM_REPORT_CATEGORY, null);
    Long scheduledId =
        reportRow.get(RS_PARAM_SCHEDULED_ID) != null
            ? Long.parseLong(reportRow.get(RS_PARAM_SCHEDULED_ID).toString())
            : null;
    return Report.builder()
        .reportId(reportId)
        .reportName((String) reportRow.get(RS_PARAM_REPORT_NAME))
        .reportType((String) reportRow.get(RS_PARAM_REPORT_TYPE))
        .reportCategory(reportCategory)
        .reportStatusDesc(
            ReportStatus.values()[(Integer) reportRow.get(RS_PARAM_STATUS_ID) - 1].getDesc())
        .submittedBy((String) reportRow.get(RS_PARAM_USER_NAME))
        .submittedById((int) reportRow.get(RS_PARAM_USER_ID))
        .submittedTime((Timestamp) reportRow.get(RS_PARAM_SUBMIT_DATETIME))
        .completedTime(completeTs)
        .lastOpeningTime(lastOpenedTs)
        .reportData(reportData)
        .reportRunLevel(reportRunLevel)
        .opened(reportOpened)
        .executionTime(executionTime)
        .scheduledId(scheduledId)
        .build();
  }
```

I know it's not the prettiest bit of code, but that's legacy system and is beside the point.

Now, I had to test that code to make sure we can read the same object and verify the fields, so I had the following 3 scenarios:

1. Clone this code in a test class. I've built a test utility that does just that. Clearly, that resulted in duplication of the same un-pretty code, which is not ideal.
2. An alternative way would be to outsource this code to some utility class and let both prod and test code use it, for the sake of avoiding duplication.
3. Also, there is a way to change access modifier of the production class and let test that.

That is an integration test that uses proper DB instance so using mocks isn't gonna do - we need to read actual data. The example is actually not the best and is only for illustration. The main question: do we reuse production code in the tests or is it best to  duplicate it?

I strongly lean toward option #1, on the premise that if we introduce a bug in the transformation in the prod code - how do we detect it? For that, I believe code segregation is the best way.

Are there any other opinions or reasons behind these, please?

Comment: I forgot to mention, that is an integration test that uses proper DB instance so using mocks isn't gonna do - we need to read actual data.

Comment: so, you're saying your choice would be to re-use the production code, @bgore?

Comment: https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity

Answer (score 1):

If you going to duplicate the code in test scope, what if some bug fix has been added in future and what if your test did't alert you about something happened on your production code flow?Also think about how you maintain your duplicate code in future.
Usually tests are not only meant to validate your present code.But they also  document and feedback/system that will notify any changes/breakages in code.

If you couldn't write a test case for your piece, then its a time to refactor your code.

On a practical note it's not always good idea to dismantle the existing working piece, it may need bit time and depth knowledge on history of code base and strong test suite.But its worth to get our hands little dirty

I would suggest any one below,

1. Refactor your code, align it with Single Responsibility and cover each unit with test case(as you stated atleast you can move them to some util).
2. integration test
3. use powermock or any similar tool to test private methods(Note : Some organisation may not like tools like powermock for security concerns)